# Adding object to an existing object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am looking for a solution in jQuery / javascript to add an object to an objectArray.
In my object I have the object "`objectArray`". Inside of this elment is a dynamic number of other objects.

How can I add i.e. this object:

```
{
        "code": "7891",
        "items": {
          "attribute": "car",
        }
```

To the object Array without overwritting the frist element? To get this:

```
"objectArray": [
  {
    "code": "1234",
    "items": {
      "attribute": "House",
    }
  },
  {
    "code": "7891",
    "items": {
      "attribute": "car",
    }
  },
],
```

I used the way with arrays and JSON.stringify() but this doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `objectArray.push(object)` which appends the `object` to the array.

More info on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    code: "7891",
    items: {
      attribute: "car"
    }
  }
];
const res = [
  {
    code: "1233",
    items: {
      attribute: "car"
    }
  },
  ...data
];

//Or
const res2 = [
  {
    code: "1233",
    items: {
      attribute: "car"
    }
  }
].concat(data);

console.log(res, res2);
```

Comment: Please don't just provide code, but instead add a description to what it does.

Comment: Understand. Thanks! But it was not `push`, upshift